# How do I make background colour of webpages change dynamically with PHP?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I have some HTML code here and I want to be able to change the background colour dynamically.

How can I do that?

Thanks for any help

### Lorem Ipsum

```
<body>
  <div class="container backgroundcolourBlue backgroundcolourRed backgroundcolourGreen backgroundcolourGrey  Font_Helvetica Font_Petitformalscript ">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="Text backgroundcolorWhite addpadding">
        <div class="header">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="textcontent">
```

Comment: The answer is "many different ways".

Comment: Question is unclear. Is the goal to change colors on each page reload? Or by another means? (Anyway, only specify *one* of the "color classes" for the element - otherwise the most-specific/last CSS rule will always win.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like that

```
 <?php 
     $class = ($page == 'home') ? 'class="bg-red"' : '';
     <body $class>
     </body>
 ?>
```

And in your style :

```
.bg-red {
   background-color:red;
}
```